# Transact-SQL procedures : why does my else loop not work?

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I need to print a list of countries together with other number of customers etc when a user enters a country name. My if loop works but the else loop doesn't work. The else loop should be executed when a user enters a country that is not in the column. It should print the message and the list of countries to choose from. Can someone say what is wrong in my code?

```
create or alter proc [usp_sales per country total plus different customer]
    @land varchar(100)
as
    if exists (select shipcountry from Sales.Orders)
    begin
        select distinct 
            shipcountry, 
            count(orderid) as CustomerTotal,
            count(distinct custid) as [Different Customer]
        from 
            sales.orders
        where 
            @land = shipcountry
        group by 
            shipcountry
    end
    else if not exists (select shipcountry from Sales.Orders)
    begin
        print 'Land nicht gefunden - Wählen Sie eines aus der Liste aus'

        select shipcountry 
        from Sales.orders
    end


exec [usp_sales per country total plus different customer] china
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line of code in the if will always return something because you have no where clause

```
select shipcountry from Sales.Orders
```

Try something like this

```
select 1 from Sales.Orders where shipcountry = @land
```

and remove the condition on the else, not vary maintianable to have the same condition reversed in both places.